# aws s3 copy fails with: 'Remote end closed connection without response'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

The last step of my lambda function is to copy a temporary s3 key to its final name (which may or may not exist). That copy succeeds most of the time, but can fail, with:

> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

```
File "/var/task/main.py", line 217, in _s3_copy
s3cli.copy_object(Bucket=dst_bucketname, Key=dst_keyname, **xtra)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
operation_model, request_dict)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 148, in make_request
return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 177, in _send_request
success_response, exception):
File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 273, in _needs_retry
caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
response = handler(**kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
caught_exception)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
caught_exception)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
attempt_number, caught_exception)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
raise caught_exception
File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 222, in _get_response
proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

What is the remedy for this? Retries? Or different client retry/timeout settings?

Note: In the lambda, this is running boto3 1.7.74 and botocore 1.10.74. The files range in size, but they are in the 2-4GiB range.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a cause for this, but it wasn't exactly obvious from the stacktraces what was going on.

Solution: It turned out to be that the policy in the role assigned to the lambda didn't allow PutObject action on the destination bucket. I've simply added the destination bucket to the list.

The way I've found this out was to bump boto3's logging verbosity. Just before the copy, I've added the following:

```
 boto3.set_stream_logger('', logging.DEBUG)
```

The first parameter is normally the name of the service, but `''` is interpreted as all services. My logging for the lambda was setup to be dumped in cloudwatch logs, so I could inspect them there.

I've discovered the following errors during CopyObject:

```
[DEBUG] 2018-11-20T10:20:37.981Z    4a230839-ecac-11e8-8412-7bf802a1306b    ConnectionError received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 372, in _make_request
httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

...repeated...

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/runtime/botocore/endpoint.py", line 222, in _get_response
proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/var/runtime/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

It looked as if there was a TypeError causing issues at first, which led me to believe that I might have run into package version incompatibilities between requests and urllib3. But it turns out that this code path is a legacy code path taken by urllib3, and is expected to be taken when other network errors occur  (see [the buffering issue on github](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/1915)). This was a red herring -- it's normal. The real cause is what triggered that in the first place.

I've spotted a few more entries before that point in the trace where the connection to the bucket's https endpoint succeeded, but no response could be read. So the connection was closed before `requests` could even read the status code to the PUT.

I would have expected to be able to at least read `<Code>AccessDenied</Code>`, which would have eased diagnosis. Other S3 calls will fail with `AccessDenied`, I'm not sure why this one is special. Perhaps this is a policy that helps protect public-facing buckets. not sure.

Anyways, adjusting the permissions fixed it.